# How to increment variable in Django template?

Tags: python, django

I was making a grid and need to declare the variable and increment it.

```
{% for new, des, i, link, published, author in mylist %}
    {% if x == 1 %}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="h-100 mt-2 row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                    <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong>
                    <h5 class="mb-0">{{new}}</h5>
                    <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{published}}</div>
                    <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{des}}</p>
                    <a href="{{link}}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                    <img class="bd-placeholder-img" src="{{i}}" width="200" height="250" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Help me to declare variable x and increment it like `x+1` inside the template

I was trying `{% with x=0 %}` but that's not working

Comment: You cannot declare a variable and increment it in the template. You do have access to `forloop.counter` inside a for-loop though.

Comment: @schwobaseggl It will be great if you show me how

Comment: Instead of `{% if x == 1 %}` just use `{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}`. You also have `forloop.counter0` which is a 0-based counter. Checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: In addition to `forloop.counter`, there are a number of other variables set - eg `forloop.first` is a boolean indicating whether this is the first iteration of the loop or not, commonly used for things like writing a header row - as it looks like you're trying to do here. `{% if forloop.first %}` should do it, more concisely than checking the counter.. See the docs for the full list: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: @schwobaseggl  thanks this method is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below:

```
{% set x = 0 %}
{% for new, des, i, link, published, author in mylist %}
    {% set x = x + 1 %}
    {% if x == 1 %}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="h-100 mt-2 row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
                <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
                    <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong>
                    <h5 class="mb-0">{{new}}</h5>
                    <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{published}}</div>
                    <p class="card-text mb-auto">{{des}}</p>
                    <a href="{{link}}" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
                    <img class="bd-placeholder-img" src="{{i}}" width="200" height="250" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Pycharm is saying `unresolved "set" tag`
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

django has a {{ forloop.counter }}. You can use this.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.